# Error in bundle when executing cron.job with Whenever

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cron, whenever

I have the following `schedule.rb`

```
every 1.minute do
  runner "User.persist_things"
end
```

But looking at my `log/cron.log` file, the output is the following:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- bundler/setup (LoadError)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from /Users/felipeclopes/projects/example/config/boot.rb:6
    from script/rails:5:in `require'
    from script/rails:5
```

I am using RVM with ruby, the current version is:

```
$ ruby --version
ruby 1.9.3p392 (2013-02-22 revision 39386) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0]
```

So it seems that the cron job is loading the incorrect ruby version, but I don't know how to fix this. Can you help me figuring out?

Comment: just do gem install bundler, and try again

Comment: I did this, but it didn't worked!

Comment: Can you post your method in the `User` model? When using runner, make sure that you are defining the method as `self.persist_things`.

Comment: It is a class method. The problem is probably regarding the wrong ruby version being loaded or something like that. It a environment issue.

Comment: Can you successfully call `User.persist_things` from the rails console  or via rake task, outside of the Whenever context?

Answer (score 5):

There is a known issue with whenever and rvm integration. I would suggest following the instructions on the whenever gem page: 
[RVM Integration](https://github.com/javan/whenever#rvm-integration)

See also: [Whenever issues related to rvm](https://github.com/javan/whenever/search?q=rvm&ref=cmdform&type=Issues)

Comment: The rvmrc file is deprecated and I am using the .ruby-version and .gemset-version, but it is not working.

Comment: Hmm, at this point, then, I would suggest uninstalling all version of Ruby, and uninstalling all gemsets, and starting from scratch. It looks to me that whenever/cron are not respecting .ruby-version and .gemset-version, and instead using the default ruby/gemset.

Answer (score 0):

You could ditch RVENV switch to something cleaner like rbenv + rbenv-binstubs

Answer (score 0):

You should have this in config/deploy.rb to make whenever work with capistrano if that's the case:

```
require 'whenever/capistrano'
...
set :whenever_command, 'bundle exec whenever'
```